# Error on convert JPA enum do PostgresSQL Enum

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to insert data into my table whose status column has an enum type but I'm facing the following error:
[image]

I mapped into my entity accordingly but it isn't work
Here's my code:

Entity (I highlighted the enum column)
[image]

PostgresSQL column props
[image]

PostgresSQL type definition
[image]

My controller and my service, respectively
[image]
[image]

My request at postman
[image]

SectionDTO
[image]

Comment: Please add your code as a text.

Answer (score 0):

if you use Hibernate 6.X

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private STATUS status;
```

if you use Hibernate 5.X
pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-types-52.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    @TypeDefs(@TypeDef(name = "pgsql_enum", typeClass = com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.basic.PostgreSQLEnumType.class))
    public class CassName {
        @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        @Type( type = "pgsql_enum" )
        @Column(name = "status", columnDefinition = "status")
        private STATUS status;
}
```

.....

Comment: Hello Ram
I already tried the first solution but it didn't work. The error persists because the JPA can't convert this data to the type enum inside the DB with this simple annotation.

The Hibernate 5.x solution don't work because I'm using the 6.x and can't even find this @TypeDef import.

Comment: use the below SQL to create the Enum in PG ```CREATE TYPE upms.status AS ENUM (
 'ACTIVE',
 'INACTIVE');```